# Implementing 'complex' functions

Tags: function-construction

I am able to work with simple functions, but I am getting really stuck with this one.
[image]

I want to use the numerical maximize function but I get error message when trying to implement it. Could someone please help me,

I have this: `data = RandomFunction[
   OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, .1, .3, 1], {0, 2000, 1}];`

Now I want to use numeric maximization to figure out these parameters. But before I do that I need to be able to implement the function in the first case, could someone please show me how?

```
   k[\[Theta]_] := -((n + 1)/2) Log[\[Pi] \[Sigma]^2] - 
   \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\), \(2\)]\)/\[Sigma]^2 - 
   1/2 Sum[Log[1 - E^(2 Subscript[\[Lambda], k])], {k, 1, n}] - 
   Sum[(Subscript[x, k] - 
   E^(-Subscript[\[Lambda]\[CapitalDelta], k]) Subscript[x, 
   k - 1])^2/(\[Sigma]^2 (1 - 
   E (-2 Subscript[\[Lambda]\[CapitalDelta], k]))), {k, 1, n}]
```

Comment: Note delta k = t_k-t_(k-1)

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated it. I am aware of Mathematica using capital for built in functions.

Comment: Now your left-hand side has the same name as a variable on the right-hand side; you're doing sth like $k(x)=k(k+1)$ or so. Also, provide a **complete** code, with a definition od the "delta k"; note also that copying your code into a notebook gives a nabla ($\nabla$) instead of a delta ($\Delta$).

Comment: Your "$k(\theta)$" is a constant function as it does not have any dependence on $\theta$. // A general advice is also not to use subscripts as they are likely to cause trouble. Also, `x` seems to be a function of `k`, so you need to write `x[k]` etc.

Comment: $\[Theta] = {\[Sigma]^2, \[Lambda]}$ is a vector parameter.

Comment: Btw, thank you so much for helping me corey979